# Reading Fortran datatypes in C++

Tags: c++

I have a .txt containing data in Fortran datatypes. I am able to read the data using Python in the following manner.

```
import  fortranformat as ff

.....#more code in between.
with open(sys.argv[1]) as fh
.....#more code in between.  
    nodeline = ff.FortranRecordReader("(I3,I10,3E12.5)")
    line = fh.readline()
    data = nodeline.read(line)
#note that all the code is not provided.
```

I was wondering if there was a way to read Fortran datatypes from C++ (without using the function substring) from the .txt file.

PS. I have not provided the complete python code because it works properly and I am only using the bit required to explain my question better.

A sample of the data in the .txt file is given below.

```
 -1         1-3.07500E+01-2.96893E+01-1.65000E+01
 -1         2-3.07500E+01 2.96893E+01-1.65000E+01
 -1         3-8.85000E+01 8.74393E+01-1.65000E+01
 -1         4-8.85000E+01-8.74393E+01-1.65000E+01
 -1         5-8.85000E+01 8.74393E+01-2.15000E+01
 -1         6-8.85000E+01-8.74393E+01-2.15000E+01
 -1         7-3.07500E+01 2.96893E+01-2.15000E+01
 -1         8-3.07500E+01-2.96893E+01-2.15000E+01
 -1         9 2.96893E+01-3.07500E+01-1.65000E+01
 -1        10-2.96893E+01-3.07500E+01-1.65000E+01
 -1        11-8.74393E+01-8.85000E+01-1.65000E+01
```

Comment: If it is only numbers you can simply use `std::ifstream`.

Comment: @HenriMenke it is not only number. It has a combination of numbers and string. Also I am using ifstream but I am not able to separate the data :(

Comment: Your example only has numbers.  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: @HenriMenke The question is not asking any debugging clarification. The question is how to read fortran datatypes in c++ as shown in python code. you don't have to downvote, if you do not know the answer to the question.

Comment: That is true but I downvoted because the question is unclear, is not reproducible from the information given, and shows no effort.

Comment: @HenriMenke finding a way to do it in python shows not effort indeed. I do not have to provide 200 lines of python code just to say that I want read fortran data types in c++.

Comment: Lesson for posterity, when writing data in Fortran, always make sure to write a space between the data. This makes it much easier to read by the eye, and to parse from other languages. In this case, e.g. FMT='(I3,1X,I10,1X,3(1X,E12.5))'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the format provided in the question, I wrote a simple Fortran program to write some data.

```
      PROGRAM TEST
      WRITE(*,FMT='(I3,I10,3E12.5)') 1, 234, 5.67, 8.9, 0.123456789
      END PROGRAM
```

I piped the output of the above program to a file `test.dat`:

```
  1       234 0.56700E+01 0.89000E+01 0.12346E+00
```

Then in C++ the data can easily be read in using `std::ifstream`.

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::ifstream ifs("test.dat");

    int i,j;
    double d,e,f;

    while (ifs >> i >> j >> d >> e >> f) {
        std::cout << i << ' ' << j << ' ' << d << ' ' << e << ' ' << f << '\n';
    }
}
```

Compiling and running outputs

```
1 234 5.67 8.9 0.12346
```

---

**Answer to the edit:**

If you have to parse such a weird format where spaces are missing, you might want to consider using a proper parser generator such as Boost.Spirit.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/support/iterators/istream_iterator.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

int main() {
    std::ifstream input("test.dat");
    input.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);
    std::vector<std::tuple<int, int, double, double, double>> entries;

    boost::spirit::istream_iterator first(input);
    boost::spirit::istream_iterator last;

    using namespace boost::spirit::x3;

    bool r = phrase_parse(first, last,
                          *(int_ >> int_ >> double_ >> double_ >> double_),
                          space, entries);

    if (!r || first != last) {
        std::cerr << "Parsing failed at " << std::string{first, last} << '\n';
    } else {
        for (auto const &entry : entries) {
            int i, j;
            double d, e, f;
            std::tie(i, j, d, e, f) = entry;
            std::cout << i << ' ' << j << ' ' << d << ' ' << e << ' ' << f
                      << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort. sorry about the previous clash. 
 I have edited the question with a sample of data from my .txt file. I am not able to separate the second chunk of data using ifstream because they are not separated with spaces. Once again thanks for your effort.